# sipdroid build eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to build sipdroid under eclipse,I have downloaded 
the source from the svn found on the site and I followed the 
instructions found on the build.txt file. 
In the second step saying to execute ant debug the ant script fails 
this is the output of the console:

`[maxsap@localhost sipdroid-read-only]$ ant debug`

> Buildfile: build.xml 
>       [setup] Android SDK Tools Revision 6 
>       [setup] Project Target: Google APIs 
>       [setup] Vendor: Google Inc. 
>       [setup] Platform Version: 1.5 
>       [setup] API level: 3 
>       [setup] Importing rules file: platforms/android-3/ant/ 
>   ant_rules_r2.xml 
>   -compile-tested-if-test: 
>   -dirs: 
>        [echo] Creating output directories if needed... 
>   -resource-src: 
>        [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources... 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:26: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'installLocation' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:31: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'targetSdkVersion' in
>   package 'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'normalScreens' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'smallScreens' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'largeScreens' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:32: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'anyDensity' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:37: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:39: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:41: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:42: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android' 
>        [null] /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/maxsapSipDroid/sipdroid-read-
>   only/AndroidManifest.xml:43: error: No
>   resource identifier found for 
>   attribute 'required' in package
>   'android'  BUILD FAILED 
>   /home/maxsap/Documents/progrs/android/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/
>   android-3/ant/ant_rules_r2.xml:220:
>   null returned: 1  note that when I do
>   ant, the script successfully 
>   completes.  but then when I import the
>   project in eclipse doing file->import-
>   existing project into workspace

The project contains errors (seems like the R.java class isn't 
present).

any suggestions? 
I have posted it for some days at the discussion group of sipdroid but no luck,I haven't got any reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey, I had similar problems which were fixed by changing the target of the project. Perhaps there is something unsupported by the earlier target?

I right clicked the project in Project explorer in Eclipse -> Properties-> Android -> Then ticked the appropriate checkbox to a later target.

Comment: Me too. Although I change android:targetSdkVersion="8" in AndroidManifest but nothing happens. So I must change it like your way and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

check project layout is the R.java in a different place? It might not be in the gen folder..in which case you need to move it I guess..

Comment: I can't find R.java in my gen folder or in my project.

Comment: sorry about that I hit enter and the comment was posted.I can't find r class as I said but I have found this post suggesting that I have to compile the class myself,how can I do that any ideas? also I get some errors on my Android.xml file. regards maxsap

Comment: ok so I deleted the problematic xml tags from Android manifest(even thought they wasn't error as eclipse complained) and the R class was compiled from the IDE but the project continued to contain errors

Answer (score 0):

i have downloaded the same project and there was a same error. but my error is resolved by adding a **project.properties** file in the project. and second thing in eclipse right click on your `project->properties->Android` and choose the appropriate target name.